# Zlib compression through PHP

Tags: php, html, compression, gzip, zlib

I would like to activate Zlib compression through PHP. What code should I use for the PHP.ini file. I'm a bit confused on the best way of setting this up. http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you can help me set up this. Or know the code for the PHP file that I can edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function read write compress small chunks you can use this function to compress big files

```
/**
* @return bool
* @param string $source
* @param string $dest
* @desc compressing the file with the zlib-extension
*/
function gzipCompress($source, $dest, $level = 5){

    if($dest == false){
        $dest = $source.".gz";

    }

    if(file_exists($source)){

        $filesize = filesize($source);
        $source_handle = fopen($source, "r");

        if(!file_exists($dest)){

            $dest_handle = gzopen($dest, "w$level");

            while(!feof($source_handle)){

                $chunk = fread($source_handle, 2048);
                gzwrite($dest_handle, $chunk);

            }

            fclose($source_handle);
            gzclose($dest_handle);

            return true;

        } else {

            error_log("The $dest already exists");

        }

    } else {

        error_log("The $source does not exist.");

    }

    return false;
}
```

To enbable zlib compression find zlib.output_compression on php.ini file in your server and change its value from 0 to 1.You can change compression level also by changing value of zlib.output_compression_level and there is zlib.output_handler to change output handle.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer sorry my question may have been written wrong. I would like to enable Zlip compression for my site. For page speed

Comment: This is what I found. Told me to edit the php.ini file and add this. --with-zlib[=DIR]
zlib.output_compression = On